# Angular2 http.post does not react on full domain name

Tags: angular

I have the follwing code:

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/login',
     JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
     { headers }
)
```

Which does not work, I don't even see an error in the browser console.
when using only 'api/login' it works, but of course on the wrong domain.
The docu just want an url, is there some CORS issue here or any other restriction
Thanks for help?

Comment: You do not need to stringfy the payload and does not need to encapsulate de header inside a object... the URL is ok, I do not think it is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http.post returns an observable, just like any http action does. You need to subscribe on it to make it run.

try this:

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/login',
    { username, password },
    { headers }
).subscribe();
```

Extra info:

subscribe can take 3 paramaters.

1. onSuccess(response), called on succes with a response from the server
2. onError(response), called on error with a response from the server
3. onComplete, called when the call is completed.

I really suggest you deep into observables

Comment: There's no need for **stringify**